# Compiling with -o3 freezes app, while -o0 works fine

Tags: iphone, xcode, optimization, architecture, opencv

I've just successfully built openCV as a static library for iOS armv7 architecture.

However, when referencing this library from an app compiled under -o3 (or -o2, -o1) the app just freezes when this library is called.

I'm guessing it's something I didn't set as build flags or options when compiling openCV that's the problem (I compiled openCV using cMake and Xcode 4) - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? It is possible the optimizations are causing synchronization issues.

Comment: Yes in places, I didn't think about that. That is definitely a possibility, will look into it.

Comment: aha - it was a threading issue. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ughoavgfhw said above, it was a threading issue. One task was being completed at an earlier stage than expected (with no checking for this), and ended up creating a recurring loop.